# ASP.NET Entity Framework BulkInsert with foreign key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Can Bulk Insert handle foreign key?

When I use Bulk Insert, the foreign key is set to 0.

I search solution from google for a while, but I can't find any idea of a solution for this problem.

Comment: Share the relevant code.

Comment: uh.. I follow this video [How to use SQL Bulk Insert | FoxLearn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSadwociM_0&t=1s)